# Gaussian and binary probability random variables numerical reconstruction

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

in my probability class I was given this question dealing with MATLAB code the purpose of which is to create and re estimate the random variables Z1, Z2, which reads as follows:

> rng('default')
>
> exps = 1e5;
>
> sigX = 6;
>
> sigY = 1;
>
> % generate some normal (Gaussian) variables
>
> X = sigX*randn(exps,1);
>
> Y = sigY*randn(exps,1);
>
> % generate a binary variable
>
> B = rand(exps,1)>0.5;
>
> % generate Z1 and Z2
>
> Z1 = B.*X+(1-B).*Y;
>
> Z2 = 0.5*(X + Y);
>
> % display histograms (1st order distribution estimate)
>
> subplot(211);
>
> hist(Z1,1000)
>
> xlabel('bins')
>
> ylabel('frequency')
>
> axis tight
>
> subplot(212);
>
> hist(Z2,1000)
>
> xlabel('bins')
>
> ylabel('frequency')
>
> axis tight

And the output graphs are the following:

[image]

The question asks us to explain the results of these graphs (what is expected or not and so forth). We are also asked to relate this question to a previous result obtained which I already solved:

> If two independent random variables X and Y which are independent from A which discretely receives one of two values {1,2} equally, defining the following random variable:
>
> [image]

then we know the following information

> [image]

And that the addition of two independent Gaussian variables is again Gaussian with sum of means and variances.

I have no idea how the MATLAB code works and how to relate the previous problem that I solved and how to explain the results so this is my problem, in explaining the results and relating the previous question. I thank all helpers out there